# Cannot recognize graphic card after installing Windows

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I have an HP desktop computer. It's default OS was Windows 7 32-bit.
Everything was fine. But when I installed generic (not for HP) Windows 7 64-bit, it does not recognize my graphic card. What would be the reason?

The main reason I need 64-bit is to fully utilize my 8 GB RAM. With 32bit Windows, only 3.24GB is usable.

CPU is Intel Core i5-2500 @3.3GHz, Graphic card is NVIDIA Quadro 600

Comment: Have you installed drivers?

Comment: When installing Win 7 32bit provided by HP, everything is done automatically, but with generic 64bit, internet connection is impossible. The computer seems not recognize ethernet port

Comment: Then simply download the driver installers on another PC. This is why it's always recommended to keep all the latest drivers ready (preferably on an external drive) *before* beginning installation of your target OS.

Answer (score 1):

This the first problem most new technicians run into when first getting involved in working with installation of Windows OS.

Generic Windows installation discs (not OEM discs) **don't include every driver ever made**, which includes the drivers for the hardware on your particular system. OEM discs (like the one HP provided you) **includes all the drivers for your particular system**, and many times includes the Windows product key, so activation and installation is very simple (minus uninstalling OEM bloatware).

**You can do one of two things**:

- Download all the missing drivers **from another computer** with an internet connection, and transfer them over with a USB drive (or a CD).
- Download only the **network adapter drivers** to a USB drive (or CD) and once you have an internet connection on the PC you're working on, download the remaining missing drivers.

Most experienced technicians download the ethernet drivers **before** doing the reinstall, that way getting the rest of the drivers is just a matter of a Google search.

**If you're not sure of which drivers to download**:

*Go to the manufacturer's website. Search by your model number, Windows version, and it will list all the current drivers for your hardware.*

---

**If the manufacturer's website doesn't work there are other methods for finding drivers**:

Sometimes Windows can automatically search for drivers and install them on its own. In my experience, **this is rare**.

For graphics cards, **if you know the model of the card** (sometimes it is written on a label physically on the card), you can go to the manufacturer's website and download the latest driver.

For mostly every other device, I use [**pcidatabase.com**](http://www.pcidatabase.com) to search by the *vendor and device ID*. To find the vendor and device ID:

Open **Device Manager**, right click the device with the missing driver (usually marked in yellow), then click **Properties**. Click the **Details** tab, then click the dropdown and select the **Hardware ID property**. The value will have the terms ***VID*** followed by four characters (this is the vendor ID), and ***PID*** followed by four characters (this is the product or device ID). You can search on [pcidatabase.com](http://www.pcidatabase.com) for the device name, and it usually includes a download link to drivers.