# Windows won't connect to a network no matter what I do

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

My windows 7 computer that I **just** formatted (about 20 minutes ago, clean install of windows) won't connect to the internet.

Before I formatted it, it worked fine.

Here's what I've tried:

- Power cycling my router/modem
- Plugging computer directly into the modem
- Buying a wifi USB (even though my computer has wifi built in), installed the drivers from a disc

Windows troubleshooter couldn't fix it. Three other computers in my house all work fine on my network. I'm assuming I'm missing a driver, however I can't connect to windows update to get the driver (and, the USB wifi thing came with a driver disc that I installed)

Right after I run the troubleshooter and connect again, it allows me to chose the type of network (home, public, work). But it still won't connect.

Comment: have you installed Chipset and Lan drivers for your motherboard after installing windows? you will have to download it from another station and sneaker-net it over, or boot from a live CD, download the driver to your local hdd and reboot into windows to install it.

Comment: No, but I have installed the drivers for my wifi USB so I figured that'd work

Comment: What does Device Manager show?  Any yellow exclamation points or unknown devices?  It also sounds as if this is a wifi network you're trying to connect to - what happens when you attempt to connect?  Do you see the SSID?  Get prompted for the password?  What does `ipconfig` show after you "connected?"

Answer (score 1):

If you did a clean install of Windows from a retail disc, then many of the drivers will be missing after the installation finishes. Most importantly, chipset, graphics cards, drivers for ethernet cards, USB hubs and devices on those hubs will be missing.

Please read my answer to a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/a/602151/201262).

It explains why the best thing to do **before** doing a retail re-install of Windows you should put the network card's drivers on a flash drive. That way you have internet after installation to fetch the rest of your drivers.

In your situation, it sounds most likely that your chipset drivers are uninstalled. Without those, most USB devices and network cards won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You indicate that you've installed a USB WiFi adapter, and that you installed the device drivers for it, but have you pointed it at your wireless network yet? There should be a system tray icon indicating network status, and clicking on it should show you a list of available wireless networks... make sure you're on one.

Comment: Yes I've tried to connect.